# list array of object remove property

Tags: javascript, angular

my array shows up with the property policy data, I would like to make a new list of policies without that property in between `policyData`.

Any idea?

```js
"policies": [{
  "policyData": {
    "policyToken": "78653321",
    "originSystemCode": "bob",

  },
  "policyData": {
    "policyToken": "78653321",
    "originSystemCode": "fe",

  }
}]
```

Comment: give me es of code

Comment: You cannot have two keys named "policyData" in your object.

Comment: yes, you can't have two key with same name. last one will override others

Comment: The data you are showing is not valid and impossible to construct. If you are receiving this from a service, contact the service provider and inform them of the invalid data they are sending.

Comment: Yeah, @HereticMonkey's comment is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must make sure your data is structured correctly and conforms to JSON standards. Each key in an object must be unique. If you are not sure if your JSON is structured correctly, you can validate it using a tool e.g. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Now. you can reshape your data by mapping the value of each `policyData` entry.

```js
const data = {
  "policies": [{
    "policyData": {
      "policyToken": "78653321",
      "originSystemCode": "bob"
    }
  }, {
    "policyData": {
      "policyToken": "78653321",
      "originSystemCode": "fe"
    }
  }]
};

const reshaped = { policies: data.policies.map(p => p.policyData) };

console.log(reshaped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I understood the question by reading your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, you will have to change the server's output in order to be able to map this data

```
{
    "policies": [
        {
            "policyToken": "78653321",
            "originSystemCode": "bob"
        },
        {
            "policyToken": "78653321",
            "originSystemCode": "fe"
        }
    ]
}
```